# Python обработка POST запроса из HTTP

Tags: python, веб-программирование, post

Есть Apache сервер с веб страницей. При нажатии кнопки `start` выполняется POST запрос.
Как данный POST запрос отловить и выполнить действие при помощи Python `def start_command():`?
Какие библиотеки нужны?
Напиши пожалуйста пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apache` не умеет запускать по `HTTP` запросам `python` скрипты. Для этого есть [`WSGI`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSGI), в частности [`uWSGI`](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Но я Вам советую использовать [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) - легковесная библиотека для работы с `REST`'ом с кучей подключаемых модулей, например, модуль для работы с формами [`Flask-WTF`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: но ведь `python` может отловить запрос `POST` и внутри него уже запустить скрипт, также написанный на `python`

Comment: @Insider ну вот `flask` именно этим и занимается

Comment: Нет. С помощью него, python отправляет что-то серверу и это можно потом посмотреть на веб странице. У меня же на оборот. Сервер отправляет что-то клиенту с python, и на этом клиенте к примеру запускается запись видео с экрана.

Comment: С помощью `Flask` по `HTTP` запросу можно запустить `python` скрипт, при этом скрипт сможет просмотреть `POST` параметры. Не это ли тебе нужно?

Comment: Flask является микрофреймворком для создания вебсайтов на языке Python.

Comment: Перефразирую немного вопрос:
Имеется Apache сервер с веб страницей - на RPi. С разными кнопками которые отправляю POST и GET запросы этому-же RPi, при помощи AJAX. Python; просто должен отлавливать запросы и их обрабатывать в своем коде - к примеру, страница говорит, запусти скрипт старт записи, и Python получив команду, запускает это в своем коде. Как происходит отлавливание этих запросов при помощи Python?
Какие библиотеки нужны? Прошу так же написать пример.

Comment: "С разными кнопками которые отправляю POST и GET запросы этому-же RPi, при помощи AJAX" - вот это я совершенно не понял. типа у вас кнопки на панели отправляют через javascript POST и GET запросы на localhost. И  Python'ом надо эти POST и GET запросы перехватывать. Все правильно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35343/discussion-between-michaelpak-and-insider).

Comment: @Insider: не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа на вопрос в комментариях -- [обновите ваш вопрос вместо](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/489396/edit).